# c# consume wsdl service 'Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'getCustomerDetails' i

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

Hi I am trying to consume a WSDL soap service in `c# console application` , the service is passed an account number and returns the details of that account.
I have tested the service using SOAP UI, all is good and working however now when I create a service class using `svcutil` to generate the class, I instantiate the client and try calling the method but it fails with the following error message. Please assist me. Please see error message and code below.

```
inner exception : There is an error in the XML document(43,9)
message : Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace CRMTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           

            var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var myednPoint = new EndpointAddress("SERVICE URL");
            var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<customerDetail_PortType>(myBinding, myednPoint);

            customerDetail_PortType client = null;

            try
            {
                getCustomerDetailsRequest request = new getCustomerDetailsRequest();
                request.customerDetailIn = new customerDetailIn();

                request.customerDetailIn.emmAccountNo = "3902269211";
                //request.customerDetailIn.IDNumber = String.Empty;
                //request.customerDetailIn.standNo = String.Empty;


                client = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
                client.getCustomerDetails(request);
                //client.getCustomerDetails()
                ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {    
                if (client != null)
                {
                    ((ICommunicationObject)client).Abort();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="EMMCRMIntegration_webServices_providers_customerDetail_Binder" />

       <readerQuotas maxDepth="999999" maxStringContentLength="999999" maxArrayLength="999999" maxBytesPerRead="999999" maxNameTableCharCount="999999" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="SERVICE URL"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 

          bindingConfiguration="EMMCRMIntegration_webServices_providers_customerDetail_Binder"
          contract="customerDetail_PortType" 
          name="EMMCRMIntegration_webServices_providers_customerDetail_Port"
      />

    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I would really appreciate your help. I tried for about an hour to fix this but no luck.